# If the range does not equal the codomain does that mean you have a kernel?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I understand the kernel is the map of everything to zero, but does that mean that the only way for a kernel who is just made up of the zero from the previous area is for the range to equal the codomain.

Comment: If Spanish or Portugese is your mother tongue, maybe it would be better to write your post in that language. I don't understand a word of what you're asking. Kernel is a set, it can mean different things depending on the structure. Monomorphisms don't have to be surjective.

Comment: Consider the map $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $x \mapsto (x,x).$ The kernel is $0$ but the range is not all of $\mathbb{R}^2.$

Answer (score 0):

No. For example, an injective linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ has zero kernel but the range is not equal to the codomain.